# How do I update nested, multi-layered records in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to store a bunch of questions and answers in the user collection, so that one user could have the following stored like this:

```
{
    _id: '34ifujia0',
    questions: [
        {
            'questionId': 'someQuestion',
            'answer': [
                {
                    'name': 'questionWithinQuestion',
                    'answer': 5
                },
                {
                     'name': 'anotherQuestionWithinQuestion',
                     'answer': 10
                }
             ]
         }
    ]
}
```

So there are multiple questions and they could be multi-layered to hold several answers. So if the big question is "Rank these colors from 1-10" (just a stupid example), the question will then hold `{name: 'red', answer: 5}, {name: 'blue', answer: 10}` for someone that really likes blue.

The problem comes when trying to store this information. I want to increment the answers by `-1` or `1` but I can't reach them.

I would LOVE to do this:

```
update({_id: userId', 'questions.questionId': questionId'},
{$inc: {'questions.$.answer[name]': 1}})
```

where `userId`, `questionId` and `name` are all the correct variables.

(**Edit: On second thought, that wouldn't work at all. I really need to use the `$` twice after all.**)

But that syntax isn't allowed. Neither is it allowed to use the `$` twice.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Per this issue [`Positional Operator Matching Nested Arrays`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831), multiple positional `$` operator can NOT be used nested arrays currently.

Maybe here is one work around

```
> db.collection.find({_id: userId, 'questions.questionId': questionId})
               .forEach(function(doc) {
                     doc.questions.map(function(q) {
                          if (q.questionId == questionId) {
                              q.answer.map(function(a) {
                                    a.answer += 1; // or -= 1;
                              });           
                          }
                     });
                     db.collection.update({_id: doc._id},
                                          {$set: {questions: doc.questions}});
    });
```